# How to open all git diff --name-only files in pycharm

Tags: bash, git, pycharm

`git diff master --name-only --relative | uniq | xargs atom` works, but

`git diff master --name-only --relative | uniq | xargs pycharm` fails with `xargs: pycharm: No such file or directory`.

When I enter `pycharm file1 file2` on command line, the files open successfully.
Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

`git diff master --name-only --relative | uniq | xargs open -a pycharm` works, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: I updated to reflect the idea that I don't know why it works :)